# Adjust image position in a fixed height container

Tags: html, css

I have an image that 267x 376 and it is in a div that is 150px x 24px and I wanted to be able to adjust what part of the image is shown rather than just the top.

You can see this here http://jsfiddle.net/h8BKc/

Right now it just shows the top left of the image but I want to be able to adjust what part of the image is shown within the div so I would move the part of the image that is trying to be viewed down to the actual image part of the card.

HTML:

```
<div class="deck-card-container">
    <div class="deck-list-card-img">
        <img src="http://hearthable.com/images/cards/1.png">
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.deck-card-container{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.deck-list-card-img{
    height: 24px;
    width:150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the `.deck-list-card-img` class `position:relative`, then the image within it,`.deck-list-card-img img`, `position:absolute` and `top` and `left` coordinates like:

```
.deck-list-card-img{
    height: 24px;
    width:150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
}
.deck-list-card-img img {
    position:absolute;
    top:-40px;
    left:-40px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/h8BKc/1/)**